# Update contents of bootstrap popover afer a successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

When I click at a target div I want a popover to be displayed (I may show a loading label as the content) and at the same time an ajax get request is sent to server to fetch the data. Once the data is back, I want to update this already open popover.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.row-client', function (e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var str = id.split('-');
        var component = str[0];
        var clientId= str[1];

        $.ajax({
            url: '../Clients/Index',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { clientId: clientId },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {

                $('.popper').popover({
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    container: 'body',
                    html: true,
                    content: data
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
});
```

Problems I encounter with is:

1. Popover is not displayed automatically at first the click or when the data is loaded. I need to keep clicking. Once the data is back and loaded, the popover is displayed at the 'next' click. Why is this so?
2. Is there any way I can keep the popover open and update the content automatically after I got the data?
3. Upon the next click to raise the popover, I want the content to be blank (it is not now). What's preventing it?

Answer (score 0):

The call to $().popover does not make the popover appear. It only adds popover behavior to the DOM element. What makes it appear later is the click, depending on the "trigger" you configure for the popover.

Try invoking $('.popper').popover() as soon as the document is ready.

And to change the contents of the popover, while it is shown, try the following:

```
$('.popper').attr("data-content","new content");
$('.popper').data('bs.popover').show();
```

Comment: It says $(...).data is undefined.

Comment: Can you share the entire HTML? Need to see what version of bootstrap and jQuery you're using

Comment: It's a big project, but the point in context is here: http://www.bootply.com/CfRb3gYE80 I have no other Javascript associated with this. Please suggest what to do. I'm using bootstrap 3.3 and jQuery 2.1.4

Comment: This might be because $('.popper') in your case returns an array of elements. I can't be sure without having access to the full running code. The data function should be defined for any element in that array.